# Purpose of indent on tape measure hook

Tags: tools, measuring

What is the purpose of the little indent on the bottom of the hooks on tape measures?

[image: tape measure hook, with arrow pointing at indent]

There's no end to the sites and videos explaining that the hole/notch is for hooking on the head of a screw, but all ignore that little indent.

Comment: The company gets to make another hook after taking that amount of metal from a hundred hooks.  101 hooks for the same metal to make 100.

Comment: In the future, the exact purpose of that little notch will be revealed and all that don't have one will suffer.  Just kidding - I have no idea.  I suspect it's there to allow you to get a slightly better grip on it while pulling the end out.

Comment: I'll bet it has something to do with chalk line clearance.

Comment: I did consider chalk lines, but I don't see how it would matter, and I've never seen anyone use it.

Comment: I'm not convinced it's to save metal either, as it looks like it's stamped and would have to be recycled, thus making any savings absolutely miniscule. Not that I know anything about the economics of tape measure manufacturing…

Comment: There is usually a “pin” or “tooth”on the backside which is to stop the end sliding off the timber face, only small but enough.

Comment: There isn't even a hint of a bump on the three I have. I've seen it though, so I know what you mean. Mine are all utterly flat, but they still have the indentation.

Comment: I don't know that this is the only thing it's good for, but it registers a pencil nicely when you're doing an arc or a straight line off an edge.

Comment: A pencil cradle or something, yes. I find this the most convincing explanation so far. Could it possibly make the line more accurate, as it's displacement would be slightly less than otherwise? I suspect any potential difference be lost in the inaccuracies of hand measurements, but I currently don't have the facility to test this.

Comment: @crip659: these are stamped, it doesn't really work like that